# How do I switch places with elements 1 and "x"? (list in a list) python

Tags: python

```
testlist = [[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,"x"]]

   for row in cups:
```

How do I switch places with elements 1 and "x"?

Comment: You mean swap those two elements? like `testlist[0][0], testlist[2][2] = testlist[2][2], testlist[0][0]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the element at `0,0` and the element at `2,2` in your nested list using the line:

```
testlist[0][0], testlist[2][2] = testlist[2][2], testlist[0][0]
```